# Play GIF only once on Discord bot (without looping)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, gif

I'm pretty new to discord.py, and I want to create a Discord bot that returns a GIF every time an emoji is sent.
All works good, but the GIF repeats (in a loop).
I want to animate the GIF only once, and after it finishes, to do nothing.
I changed the value of the GIF to repeat only once, but it's not working on Discord.

**The GIF:**

[image]

**The Cog (`dice.py`):**

```py
class Dice(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
         
    @commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
    async def dice(self, message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        if message == "" or ":game_die:":
            dice_nr = random.randint(1, 6)
            url = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/6eba610ia9/WhiteaBot/master/whitea/assets/dice/{dice_nr}.gif"
            
            embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.random())
            embed.set_image(url=url)
            await message.channel.send(embed = embed)

    
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Dice(bot))
```

I have an idea for a fix, but I think this is not the solution:
After 1 second (after the GIF's execution), *to edit the message with an image from the GIF (the last frame of the GIF)*.
I don't know if this is a good idea because some users don't have a good internet connection, and if it is possible to load during the GIF's execution or something. I don't know.

Comment: The gif does only play once, but you can delete the message by doing `await send(..., delete_after=seconds)`.

Comment: Yeah! I know, the gif sent by me is repeat once, but the discord bot repeat my gif over and over again

Comment: Does it only happen with embeds? I only tried it by uploading the file directly. That one only plays once (but if you go to another channel and go back then it will play again, which is to be expected)

Comment: It happen with with embeds and without embeds, idk why, when I'm send the same link with gif, it repeat once and then it stops

Comment: It could be the url getter then. You can add a few seconds of frames that don't change anything, and then just delete it or edit it out into a static image.